# counter function in R

Tags: r, database, counter

my database in R is 15k of rows, I need help to figure out how to count some values in my data.

here first 8 rows of my database.

```
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
id1 <- c(100,200,100,400,200,200,300,200)
id2 <- c(200,400,200,300,400,100,400,100)
result<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
tables <- data.frame(day,id1,id2,result)
```

and that's what I'm looking for:

```
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
id1 <- c(100,200,100,400,200,200,300,200)
id2 <- c(200,400,200,300,400,100,400,100)
result<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
HTH1 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
HTH2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,2,0,3)
tables <- data.frame(day,id1,id2,result,HTH1,HTH2)
```

0 in "result" means id1 lost the match, 1 that he won.
I want to know how many matches id1 won against id2 previously (before that row) and the same for id2.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: The `HTH1` in expected result doesn't matches rules. By row 5th ID1 has won twice but your expected output says `0`.

Comment: As I understand your question I think you are looking for a cumulative sum: `cumsum(result)`. But looking your data it does not match with your description of the problem.

Comment: @MirkoPiccolo Look at my answer and confirm if that is something you were looking for. Otherwise let us know your expected output.

Comment: I cheked the expected result, it's correct. I want to count how many matches id1 or id2 won against the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First form a team using combination of `id1` and `id2`. The `min` and `max` of `id1` and `id2` will be used to create a combination for a team. Meaning `id1=100, id2=200` and `id1=200, id2=100` should be considered as same team.

Then calculate how many times `id1` (say `min` member) has won and how many times `id2` (say `max` member) has won. Use `dplyr::lag` to find number of times win before current row. Now the number of times a team has won should be placed in right column `HTH1` for `id1` and `HTH2` for `id2` to get desired result.

```
library(dplyr)

tables %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(minId = min(id1,id2), maxId = max(id1,id2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(minId, maxId) %>%
  mutate(WinOfMin = lag(cumsum(ifelse(id1<id2, result==1, result==0)),default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(WinOfMax = lag(cumsum(ifelse(id1<id2, result==0, result==1)),default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(HTH1 = ifelse(id1==minId, WinOfMin, WinOfMax )) %>%
  mutate(HTH2 = ifelse(id2==maxId, WinOfMax, WinOfMin )) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-minId,-maxId, -WinOfMin,-WinOfMax) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   day id1 id2 result HTH1 HTH2
# 1   1 100 200      1    0    0
# 2   2 200 400      0    0    0
# 3   3 100 200      1    1    0
# 4   4 400 300      0    0    0
# 5   5 200 400      1    0    1
# 6   6 200 100      0    0    2
# 7   7 300 400      0    1    0
# 8   8 200 100      1    0    3
```

Comment: I want to see only matches won by the same id1 against id2 (or viceversa), not how many matches he won previously.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Have a look. You can drop `grp` column if you want. I kept it explain the answer.

Comment: could you please help me to understand the code?
btw still not the output that i need. In your count you add the previous matches result and the actual match. Is it possible to count only matches that occurred before the single row?

Comment: @MirkoPiccolo Counting the matches till previous row is possible. Let me explain my code. First I have made a `grp` which represent 2 unique team. You can think `100-200` or `200-100` will be same. Now I'm calculating count when either of those has won. Say for example `100-200` group...100 has won 3 times and 200 has won once. The last row should have shown `HTH1=1   HTH2=3`

Comment: @MirkoPiccolo Yes, you were right. Your expected result was correct. I have updated my answer and now results are matching with your expected result. I understand the logic you wanted. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to decompose the problem into components that work on a single group, and then to use `group_by()` to apply that function to each group.

The first challenge is the 'wins to date', which for a vector of results `x` I write as

```
wins_to_date <- function(x)
    cumsum(x) - x
```

This can be easily verified for sample vectors, including the important case `wins_to_date(integer())`. It also applies to logical vectors, which is probably a better way of thinking of the `result` column. Another implementation would be `lag(cumsum(x), default = 0)`.

Suppose I have all results between two teams, and I want to find the wins to date of the 'home' (first) team. I need to know the wins to date of each team, so I create a variable `idx` to choose 1 team (the 'smaller') and determine whether it is the 'home' or 'away' team. I then calculate the wins to date of t1 by constructing the wins using `ifelse()`, and similarly for t2. Finally, I use `ifelse()` to select wins to date for the 'home' team.

```
home_wins_to_date <- function(home, away, x) {
    idx <- home < away
    t1_wins <- wins_to_date(ifelse(idx, x, 1 - x))
    t2_wins <- wins_to_date(ifelse(idx, 1 - x, x))
    ifelse(idx, t1_wins, t2_wins)
}
```

The 'away' wins to date can be calculated with the same function, but with the result vector inverted

```
away_wins_to_date <- function(home, away, x)
    home_wins_to_date(home, away, 1 - x)
```

Having developed solutions for one pair of teams, we use `group_by()` to form groups, and update `tables` using our functions

```
tables %>% 
    group_by(g1 = pmin(id1, id2), g2 = pmax(id1, id2)) %>%
    mutate(
        id1_wins_to_date = home_wins_to_date(id1, id2, result),
        id2_wins_to_date = away_wins_to_date(id1, id2, result)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>% select(-g1, -g2)
```

By way of commentary, I think that `result` should be more descriptively named and a logical variable. Using `pmin()` and `pmax()` to form groups instead of `rowwise()` / `max()` / `min()` is an example of vectorization instead of iteration, and will generally be (much) more performant on large data sets. The logic of the solution here is the same as @MKR , but I find it much more helpful to solve the problem for one group, and to capture that solution as a stand-alone function (`home_wins_to_date()`), rather than to confound the logic of the solution with the transformation operations of dplyr -- one can reason about and test the function in a much more modular fashion.